# Is there any possible way to join 2 tables from 2 different databases that use 2 different DbContexts?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

So, I'm trying to run the following queries:

```cs
 var qarDevicesAffected = from a in context.Alerts
 join d in context.Devices on a.ResourceId equals d.Id
 where !d.Inactive && !a.Inactive && a.Name.Equals(alertName)
 select new AffectedEntity.Device
 {
     Id = a.Id,
     DeviceId = d.Id,
     TenantId = d.TenantId,
     OperatorName = context.Operators
     .Select(o => new { o.Id, o.Name })
     .First(o => o.Id == d.TenantId).Name,

     DeviceSerialNumber = d.SerialNumber,
     CellModuleId = d.CellModule.Id,
     CellModuleSerialNumber = d.CellModule.SerialNumber,
     LastCheckIn = d.LastCheckIn,
     LastDownload = d.LastDownload,
     LastPackageCreation = d.LastPackageCreation,
     TailNumber = d.Tail.TailNumber,
     TailId = d.Tail.Id,
     CreationDate = oldDate == "CheckIn" ? d.LastCheckIn.Value : role == "LastDownload" ? d.LastDownload.Value : d.LastPackageCreation.Value,
     IsPinned = parameters.PinnedIds != null && parameters.PinnedIds.Contains(d.TenantId)
     };

     var avWifiDevicesAffected = from a in context.Alerts
     join d in dataSyncDbContext.Device on a.ResourceId equals d.DeviceId
     join p in dataSyncDbContext.PostedFile on a.ResourceId equals p.DeviceId
     join c in dataSyncDbContext.CheckIn on a.ResourceId equals c.DeviceId
     where d.Status != "ACTIVE" && !a.Inactive && a.Name.Equals(alertName)
     select new AffectedEntity.Device 
     {
         Id = a.Id,
         DeviceId = d.DeviceId,
         TenantId = a.TenantId,
         OperatorName = context.Operators
         .Select(o => new { o.Id, o.Name })
         .First(o => o.Id == a.TenantId).Name,

         DeviceSerialNumber = d.SerialNumber,
         LastCheckIn = c.UpdatedDate,
         LastDownload = p.CreatedDate,
         TailId = Guid.Parse(d.TailId)
      };

  var devicesAffected = qarDevicesAffected.Concat(avWifiDevicesAffected);
```

And I end up getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
> Cannot use multiple DbContext instances within a single query
> execution. Ensure the query uses a single context instance.

It seems obvious that EF Core just does not support this, so, is there a way around using queries that would get me the same result? (Join 2 tables from 2 different dbContexts)

Comment: You would have to use LINQ to Entities to get the data separately, then you can use LINQ to Objects to join the two local collections. That means calling `ToList` or `ToArray` after your two EF queries to get those local collections in the first place.

Comment: I'd recommend writing raw SQL instead of client-side joins, which can degrade performance significantly; not just query's, but everything else's performance too.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu how would you write such a sql for 2 different databases with two separate DbContexts,  like the question states? They could be different types of databases on complete different computers.

Comment: @JHBonarius SQL Server, for example, can do that with `OPENROWSET()`. It would still be slow, but wouldn't overload the client at least.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu but what if the other dbcontext is msql or some other db type? Will sql server be able to read that?

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, I believe it can connect to any ADO/OLEDB provider based DB, but my experience with that is old. You should check SQL Server docs.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu might be advanced stuff. Without a good description or example the OP might not be able to use that.

Comment: Can't you merge the contexts? Is there a reason for having multiple contexts?

Answer (score 1):

EF Core is an ORM. It wraps raw sql and object mapping behind a nice interface. You can use its Linq-to-Entities functionality to construct a query, which will be converted to sql. However, with two different databases and db contexts, EF core has no idea how to combine them to one sql statement.

If the databases are on one server, you'll have to manually (sql) join the tables and you can use something like Dapper for lower level ORM.

If the databases are on separate server, you must see why EF Core is having a hard time, as there is no simple solution. The relatively simple solution would be to have separate queries and join them in memory. This could have a big performance impact, but there is no good alternative. You can switch from Linq-to-entities (IQueryable) to normal Linq (IEnumerable) by calling `.AsEnumerable()`. (There also are async options, but that's a more complex story)

In your case, I would split it up into several queries, fetching the exact data you want. Instead of big expensive joins, that just fetch a lot of data. I.e. you first get the `Alerts` data with the appropriate filter, and then get the appropriate columns in the other table based on matching `alert.ResourceId`. You can do that by putting the resourdeids together in an array, and filter the tables with with something like

```cs
.Where(x => resourceIds.Contains(x.DeviceId)
```

You will finally have to do some object mapping yourself

Comment: @JGBonarius The approach you mentioned in the last paragraph was actually the way I was planning to solve the issue, the thing is, after those queries that I showed, there are a couple more queries with the result table of the queries I showed, So the data is managed as queries until the very end where is put together in a list and sent as a response to the api call. So, right now im thinking of writing all the expensive queries in a stored procedure in the db. So all of the table joins would be done without implementing EF Core and then run the stored procedure with EF Core.